# Creating a new tab in Browser extension and calling a function once its content is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I am working on a browser extension, that opens a website in a new tab and checks if the user is logged in on the website.

```
//Inside background-script.js
var creating = browser.tabs.create({
     url: "https://www.mywebsite.com/"
});
creating.then(onSuccess, onError);
function onSuccess(tab) {
     console.log(tab.id);
     ports[tab.id].postMessage({msgType: 'CheckLoginStatus'}); //Send a message to content-script to check the login status.
}
```

The problem is that the function onSuccess is called after the tab is created but before the content of the "https://www.mywebsite.com/" has been loaded in the tab. Is there way to delay this function call till the tab is completely loaded or at-least get the status of the tab to know if its loaded.

Comment: You can send a message from the content script to onMessage listener in the background script or switch to [programmatic injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59298657) or use a temporary chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener to wait for the tab id to load.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Is it possible to call onMessage from content script only when the tab was opened by the background script? Because the user might visit the website on its own without the extension requesting it and then this message should not be send.

Comment: You can sort it out in the background script e.g. set some global variable to tab's id in onSuccess and then compare it to sender.tab.id in onMessage.

Comment: You've tagged this as both a Google Chrome extension and a Firefox extension, but you are using the `browser.*` namespace, which is Firefox specific (assuming you're not using some shim to add the `browser.*` namespace to Chrome). If you want things to be for both Chrome and Firefox, then you should be using the `chrome.*` namespace (and callbacks), which is supported by both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: You show nothing about how you are interacting with the page (i.e. you don't show your content script). The way you've structured this, it's really an [XY problem](//www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). There's really no reason, in this code, to wait for the content to be loaded. Waiting for the document to be ready can easily be done in your content script. If you really want to know the loading status of the page from the background script, then you can get that from the [`tabs.onUptated()` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated).

Comment: I prefer to use the [W3C Draft Community Group](https://browserext.github.io/browserext/) suggested namespace for both Firefox and Chrome. And there are ways in which you can make the `browser.*` keyword accepted in Chrome.

Comment: Currently the content script are not yet loaded at the time the message is send through `postMessage({msgType: 'CheckLoginStatus'})` so the content of content script is irrelevant in this particular case.   
Thanks, I will try to use `tabs.onUpdated()` in the onSuccess method.